# Vue: Reset the selected form on a click of a button

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

```
<b-row class="mb-3">
   <b-col>
      <div class="float-right">
         <b-form-select
            v-model="selected"
            :options="options"
            ></b-form-select>
      </div>
   </b-col>
   <b-col>
      <b-button
         id="show-btn"
         variant="dark"
         class="text-white"
         :disabled="!this.selected"
         @click="showModal"
         >Add Data</b-button
         >
   </b-col>
</b-row>
```

I have select field and a button to add different type of data like image, block, paragraph like below:

```
options: [
{ value: null, text: "Please select an option" },
{ value: "image", text: "Image" },
{ value: "block", text: "Block" },
{ value: "paragraph", text: "Paragraph" },
{ value: "link", text: "Link" },
],
```

All the forms will be open in a modal so inside the modal I have applied if conditions I like this:

```
<div v-if="selected === 'image'">
   <image></image>
</div>
<div v-if="selected === 'paragraph'">
   <paragraph></paragraph>
</div>
<div v-if="selected === 'block'">
   <block></block>
</div>
```

I have different fields for different type like below:

```
image_form: {
text: {
en: "",
np: "",
},
caption: {
en: "",
np: "",
},
image: "",
type: "",
},
paragraph_form: {
description: {
en: "",
np: "",
},
images: [],
},
```

if the user want to add an image s/he will see the image form inside the modal and if they want to add paragraph the will get paragraph modal and it applies to all. Since I am using same form to add and edit the form, it is field with data if I click edit before adding. So I want to reset the image form on a click of the `ShowModal` button if the user select image from the dropdown and this also applies to all. How can I do that? In simple words I want to reset the form that is going to be seen in the modal after the click of the `ShowModal` button.

Answer (score 0):

### Create a function like this

```
clearForm() {
  this.image_form.text.en = "";
  this.image_form.text.np = "";
  this.image_form.caption.en = "";
  // etc.
}
```

Add at the beginning of the function

```
showModal() {
  this.clearForm();
  // your code ...
}
```

I may have misunderstood the problem, please update the question and let me know, I will try again.